# real analysis exam review question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Suppose $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and there is $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0) = 1$. Prove that $|f\,'(c)| > 2$ for some $c \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Can you show any work you've done so far? To add a hint as well: you're going to need the mean value theorem.

Comment: after applying the mean value theorem to the first two cases, it yeilds: $f(1/2) / 1/2$ and similarly $-f(1/2)/ -1/2$. How do i continue to prove that the derivative of f is always greater than 2?

Comment: It's definitely not *always* greater than 2. It'll be greater than or equal to 2 for *some* $c$, as you've said.  It might be $\geq$ and not $>$ -- I'm not sure.


Depending on if $x_0>1/2$ or $x_0<1/2$, apply the mean value theorem to $a=0$ and $b=x_0$ or to $a=x_0$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider three cases, $x_0<\frac12$, $x_0>\frac12$, and $x=\frac12$. In each of the first two cases simply apply the mean value theorem on an appropriate interval. You’ll have to work a little harder in the third case; try to show that there must be an $x_1\in\left(0,\frac12\right)$ such that $f(x_1)\ne 2x_1$ or an $x_1\in\left(\frac12,1\right)$ such that $f(x_1)\ne2(1-x_1)$ and then apply the mean value theorem on an appropriate interval.

Comment: Or, just one of those cases and then apply that result to the function $f(1-x)$.

Comment: This only yields the existence of $c$ such that $|f'(c)|\geqslant2$.

Comment: @Did: Too true. Fixed now, though.